# "A feeling of content" or "A feeling of contentment"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm a native English user. I am used to using "content" as a noun, adjective and verb but when I use it as a noun, I usually use content rather than contentment. I checked the dictionaries and both are correct.

But which is more common and what's the difference if both are correct? Any nuance difference? I rarely use "contentment" as I feel the word sounds a bit cheesy and I don't use a "bigger" sounding word when a simpler word is available.

I used "content" as a noun in that form (and not as contents in a box) and somebody corrected me saying it's "contentment". I'm very sure I have seen "content" used in that form in many newspapers and books over my 33 years. Who's right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [*content*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/content?q=content) as you have there. An example from the link:

> the greater part of the century was a time of content

The main difference (according to the dictionary I linked to) is that *content* as a mass noun means "a state of satisfaction" whereas [*contentment*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contentment?q=contentment) means "a state of happiness and satisfaction".

As to the popularity of the phrases in your title:

[image: Google ngram of "a feeling of content" vs "a feeling of contentment"]

(Click the image to go to the site)

Google Ngrams clearly shows that *content* used in that way has greatly decreased in popularity in the last eighty years. That doesn't mean it's wrong, but it could become archaic usage over the next few decades.